# FluentMySQL migration fails when building with docker-compose but not when building from Xcode

Tags: docker-compose, vapor, fluent-mysql

I'm getting the following crash when using docker-compose with Vapor & FluentMySQL.

```
api_1  | [ INFO ] Migrating 'mysql' database (/app/.build/checkouts/fluent/Sources/Fluent/Migration/MigrationConfig.swift:69)
    api_1  | Fatal error: Error raised at top level: NIO.ChannelError.connectFailed(NIO.NIOConnectionError(host: "db", port: 3309, dnsAError: nil, dnsAAAAError: nil, connectionErrors: [NIO.SingleConnectionFailure(target: [IPv4]db/172.27.0.2:3309, error: connection reset (error set): Connection refused (errno: 111))])): file /home/buildnode/jenkins/workspace/oss-swift-5.1-package-linux-ubuntu-18_04/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 200
```

Migration fails when using:

`migrations.add(model: Model.self, database: .mysql)`

If I remove that so no Models are migrated the app builds without errors and I am able to access it at http://localhost/.

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  api:
    image: vaporapiimage
    ports:
      - 80:8080
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: db
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
      SLEEP_LENGTH: 7
      MYSQL_PORT: 3309
    depends_on:
        - db
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.1
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "3309:3306"
```

It builds and runs as expected locally from Xcode (as in without Docker).

If the `api` service is commented out then the `db` service will run on its own and create the database on first run.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
Replacing the `api` with Adminer results in being able to access the `db` through Adminer in the browser. So the `db` service is accessible and it seems as if the issue is with Vapor/Fluent (or rather my use of them):

```
  admin:
    image: adminer
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had mapped the port for `db` to 3309 so that it didn't conflict with the host MYSQL but had also set the ENV 'MYSQL_PORT' to 3309 when that should have been kept as the default 3306 because that was for communication between containers.